# What happens with customizations when updating/migrating MUI to a new release?

Tags: material-ui, customization

I’m working as a UX Designer at my company, and would like to transition into using the Material UI component library for our company applications.

We would like to make customizations to some of the components, such as:

- Changing colors an shapes (CSS)
- Adding custom components (thus having to make changes to the source code)

But before we start using the library, we would like to get the following questions answered:

Will these customizations made to the library be retained when migrating/updating to a new release of the Material UI library?

Could we face any other issues when migrating/updating?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.